# Form Multiselect option is only returning 1 option in message

Tags: php, html, forms, email

this is my first time making a form, and I have multi-select option but I think I'm missing out something because the form is working but when selecting multiple options the email I receive is only showing 1 option.

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Services</p>
<select data-placeholder="Responsible For...." multiple class="chosen-select full_width"  name="service" tabindex="-1">
<option value="Medical">Medical</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
<option value="Construction">Construction</option>
<option value="IT Services">IT Services</option>
</select>

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

send.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Type: $service \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "itssonu4564@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: `$service = join(', ', $_POST['service']);` It is an array. This will list them up as a string, separated by comma.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried this but it's ending up blank and not returning anything in services in my email

Comment: Blank normally points to an error. Check the error.log or try `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to show them in the browser. What is the http code?

Comment: @MarkusZeller It says "Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in......on line 5" which is the services array line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a small change in your HTML. Add a bracket pair to the name attribute, to make PHP it recognize it as an array.

```
<select multiple name="service[]">
```

Afterwards in PHP you can use

```
$service = implode(', ', $_POST['service']);
```

To get all services as a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

The name of select option should be array[] type

```
      name="service[]"
```